# Cylinder1 works fine, but cylinder2 gives error?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "cylinderType.h"  

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cylinderType cylinder1(4.5, 6.75);
    cylinderType cylinder2;

    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);

    cout << "***** Cylinder 1 *****" << endl;
    cylinder1.print();
    cout << endl;

    cylinder2.setRadius(3.75);
    cylinder2.setHeight(8.25);

    cout << "***** Cylinder 2 *****" << endl;
    cylinder2.print();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

## cylinderType implecation

```
#include <iostream>
#include "circleType.h"
#include "cylinderType.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

cylinderType::cylinderType(double r, double h):circleType(r)
{
    setHeight(h);
}

void cylinderType::print()
{
     cout << "Radius = " << getRadius()
     << ", height = " << height
     << ", surface area = " << area()
     << ", volume = " << volume();
}

void cylinderType::setHeight(double h)
{
    if (h >= 0)
        height = h;
    else
        height = 0;
}

double cylinderType::getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

double cylinderType::area()
{
    return 2 * 3.1416 * getRadius() * (getRadius() + height);
}

double cylinderType::volume()
{
    return 3.1416 * getRadius() * getRadius() * height;
}
```

## circleType implemecation

```
#include <iostream>
#include "circleType.h"

using namespace std;

void circleType::print()
{
     cout << "Radius = " << radius
     << ", area = " << area()
     << ", circumference = " << circumference();
}

void circleType::setRadius(double r)
{
    if (r >= 0)
        radius = r;
    else
        radius = 0;
}

double circleType::getRadius()
{
    return radius;
}

double circleType::area()
{
    return 3.1416 * radius * radius;
}

double circleType::circumference()
{
    return 2 * 3.1416 * radius;
}

circleType::circleType(double r)
{
    setRadius(r);
}
```

I dont understand where the problem is. Cylinder1 will evaluate perfectly fine, however clyinder2 will not when both arguments are passed before the print function for cylinder 2 is called...

Comment: Well I don't understand either, but that's probably because I have no idea what the `cylinderType` is or what its functions and data look like.

Comment: ill get my header files put up

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are they compiler errors, or runtime errors?

Comment: Could you add more information, first the cylinderType as other points out, but also the output of you code could help. Please edit your post to do that. I suggest you also have a look to our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq Good luck!

Comment: Does that help anymore @ForceMagic

Comment: Is the actual error a trade secret?

Comment: the error that I am getting is: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "cylinderType::cylinderType()", referenced from: _main in driver.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @SebastianABaker What is the output expected? What do you mean "evaluate", you mean when it gets print, it doesn't print what you are expecting?

Comment: it should print out the radius, the height, the volume, and the area of cylinder1 and cylinder2 when ran...cylinder1 prints out perfectly, but cylinder2 does not. WHen all cylinder2 code is commented out, the program will compile without any errors and the output for cylinder1 will be correct.

Comment: Well it is pretty clear isn't it? The error says you haven't defined `cylinderType::cylinderType()` and the code you've posted has no such definition. What more is there to say? Do you think you've defined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, note that you don't have a default constructor for cylinderType, and I also don't see a setRadius method for it (given that you provided your whole code of course).

Comment: This is pure speculation and not useful as an answer. The included sliver of code gives the impression cylinder inherits from circle, and if so, circle provides that implementation.

Comment: it does inherit it from circle... the error that I am getting is:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cylinderType::cylinderType()", referenced from:
      _main in driver.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)